# Express server returns 404 for some paths but not for others

Tags: node.js, express, routes, gulp

I have an express server with the tree structure below:

[image]

So essentially the `backend` folder is where I serve files from, and it has its own npm packages. I have my views and static assets configured like this:

```
// backend/app.js
...
app.use('/login', controllers.login);

app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

app.set('views', express.static(__dirname + '/backend/views'));
```

```
// backend/controllers/login.js
...
app.get(
    '/',
    function(req, res) {
        res.render('login');
    }
)
...
```

```
// package.json of root folder (i.e. outside /backend)
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cd backend && npm start"
  },
...
```

```
// package.json of /backend folder
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp prep && pm2-runtime server.js"
  }
...
```

```
// gulpfile (in root folder i.e. outside /backend)
...
function moveToServer(cb) {
  src(['dist/**'])
  .pipe(dest('backend'));
  cb();
}

exports.prep = series(buildAssetsAndSaveToDistFolder, moveToServer);
...
```

This works well locally, so from the root folder I simply do `npm start` and gulp builds assets, moves them into the backend folder, and the server is started. I can access it using localhost and all is well. However I'm trying to do the same on a DO droplet and I'm seeing mostly the same behavior except that the stuff in the `backend/assets/` folder always fail to load and give a 404 error. This is quite odd because the stuff in the `backend/images` folder load without problems, but I've checked and double-checked and there are indeed files in `backend/assets`, but they just won't load. To be clear, a request like `http://example.com/images/logo.png` succeeds, but `http://example.com/assets/css/styles.css` gives `404 Not Found`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure yet but it looks like it has something to do with the nested folders

Comment: I'm assuming it has something with directory traversal privileges... the way you are trying to use it, anyone would be able to access your directories. I suggest if you want that file available to the API, specify the route until the css folder

Comment: Not too sure what you mean, can you post an answer with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue with just stuff in "assets" not loading, spent a couple of hours trying to debug this, and I finally found the cause for my problem. Sharing this in case it helps anyone else.

The problem was in my nginx configuration. I was using the default reverse-proxy configuration that Digital Ocean set up for me.

```
# Default server configuration
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name hellonode;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
               gzip_static on;
               expires 12h;
               add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
}
```

In this configuration, any "assets" URI is not proxied, and that messes up the routing for Express. I just removed that location block and it fixed my problem.
However, it's trying to do a good thing with caching big assets. I believe the same caching controls can be set in Express instead of nginx though.